# Exchange 2010 database FailedAndSuspended

Tags: exchange-2010, dag

Some of our Exchange databases regularly end up with a status of `FailedAndSuspended`. I think this is probably because the databases were set up with Circular Logging and the backup copy of the database misses some transactions from the circular log.

Once a database is in the FailedAndSuspended state with a circular log, is there any way to resume replication or do I have to reseed from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per microsoft's documentation, once you go past the end of the circular log, the only way to recover is to restore the database from a backup and replay the backed up log. but this only works if your backup of the database and log plus the current log contain all of the transactions up to the current point with no gaps.